# Python in Buildroot - PyDrive errors

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, buildroot, pydrive

I am attempting to use an application in my buildroot target which uses PyDrive.

I am receiving the following errors:

```
# python driveapp.py
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driveapp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/sha.py", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name sha1
```

What modules am I missing? Can anyone help?

DD

Answer (score 5):

You are missing `BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON_HASHLIB` option. Perform following actions:

- enebale this option via `make menuconfig`
- remove your target Python `rm -fr output/build/python-2.7*`
- invoke `make` to rebuild Python with hashlib module